# Inclusion of polytopes

Tags: convex-geometry, polytopes, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls, decision-problems

Let $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ be polytopes in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that
$C_{1}=conv\left(  V\right)  $ with $V$ being a set of vertices. If
$V\subseteq C_{2}$, my question is $C_{1}\subseteq C_{2}$?

Comment: In general false as $C_2$ can be concave. If $C_2$ is convex, then $C_1 \subset C_2$.

Comment: I meant bounded convex hulls. In this case as you claim it is true.

Comment: Yes it is true if by polytope you mean a bounded convex set... a proof via element chasing should be straightforward using the theorem here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Convexity/What_is_a_convex_set%3F

Answer (score 0):

- let $V$ the vertex set of a pentagon. Thus $C_1$ = pentagon.
- use for $C_2$ the vertex-inscribed pentagram, i.e. a faceting of $C_1$.
- then $C_1\nsubseteq C_2$.

--- rk

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the convex hull $conv(V)$ is the smallest convex set containing $V$ or equivalently the intersection of all convex sets that contain $V$. Using the latter definition, if $C_2$ is convex, for any $p \in C_1$, we must have $p \in C_2$ since otherwise it wouldn’t have landed in the intersection. Therefore, $C_1 \subseteq C_2$.

As pointed out in the comments, it’s easy to find a counterexample with concave $C_2$, so you need the convexity of $C_2$.